# awk to find the multiple pattern in a line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have file file1.txt /file2.txt When I run the awk command with boundary search between "Type header call_header " and "END" it print the lines below END also .
Example :-

### File1.txt

```
Type header call_header 
abc , def , ghi , 
jkl ,mno 
END 
Define call_header 
type as call_header
```

### Fil2.txt

```
Type head call_header
data1, data2, voice ,
mms , mms2 
END
Define call_header 
type as call_header
```

I have tried:

```
awk '/^Type (header|head) call_header$/,/^END?$/'  {print} file1.txt
```

However, it is printing other lines also .

Need Below data only :

```
Type header call_header 
abc , def , ghi , 
jkl ,mno 
END
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `awk` invocation is incorrect:

```
awk '/^Type (header|head) call_header$/,/^END?$/'  {print} file1.txt
```

Here, `awk` would search for a file called `{print}`.

The whole script should be within the single quotes:

```
awk '/^Type (header|head) call_header$/,/^END?$/ {print}' file1.txt
```

Or, alternatively (shortening the first regular expression slightly and getting rid of `{ print }` completely),

```
awk '/^Type head(er)? call_header$/,/^END?$/' file1.txt
```

Tested with OpenBSD `awk`, `mawk` and GNU `awk`.

With `sed`, this is remarkably similar to the above:

```
sed -nr '/^Type head(er)? call_header$/,/^END?$/p' file1.txt
```